# How to create string/list of string with symbol in kdb?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a table with one column of strings, I want to create a new column with type string, and ` in front of each string item. How do I do that? 
 example:

**Old**:

```
a
b
c
```

**New**:

```
"\`a"
"\`b"
"\`c"
```

Comment: If you like the answer from Thomas Smyth you presumably don’t want those backslashes in the result.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution (faster in this scenario):

```
q)update b:flip ("`";a) from tab
a b
------
a "`a"
b "`b"
c "`c"
```

Answer (score 3):

Take the following table as an example:

```
q)show tab:([]a:("a";"b";"c"))
a
-
a
b
c
```

To get a new column with the backtick in front you need to append `` "`" `` to each line:

```
q)update b:("`",'a) from tab
a b
------
a "`a"
b "`b"
c "`c"
```

If the column consists of symbols then it just needs to be converted to a string first:

```
q)tab2:([]a:`a`b`c)
q)update b:("`",'string a) from tab2
a b
------
a "`a"
b "`b"
c "`c"
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answers your question please consider accepting it as an answer, this will help people who may revisit this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people, more familiar with SQL than with q, pose questions in terms of tables, when they need only handle vectors; and create new columns where all that is needed is a variable – or a value to pass as an argument.

```
q)"`",'tab[`a]
"`a"
"`b"
"`c"
```

Of course, the `a` column of `tab` is nothing but the vector `"abc"`, so

```
q)"`",'"abc"
"`a"
"`b"
"`c"
```

might be all you need.

See:

- http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#join
- http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:
update ("`",/:a) from tab